# Ansible overwrite var on false condition

Tags: ansible

I have an issue on my Ansible playbook.
Indeed, I need to store a variable, e.g. `test`.

This is what my playbook looks like

```yaml
- name: Set test var
  set_fact:
    test: "OK"
  when: true
- name: Set test 
  set_fact:
    test: "KO"
  when: false
```

The issue is: after I run this part of the playbook, if I want to reuse this variable, I can't because Ansible find it as undefined.
According to me, Ansible unset variables before it runs the second task with the `false` condition.
Is that right?

Is there a way not to have this problem and to keep the value of my variable `test`?

Comment: _According to me, Ansible unset variables before it runs the second task_ > that's not true. Ansible does not unset variables and you cannot unset variable either, you can blank them or null them, but you cannot unset them. If you have multiple plays in a playbook, though, this is a really different kind of fish, but your limited example won't help here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it's very usefull. I make some new searches and I found that set_fact module doesnt set fact accros multipe hosts but only for one host. So my issue is here and I dont show this in my code example :/. I run over 2 host and var is undefined for the second one :). Now, I'm looking for a solution for global var in playbook :)

Comment: You should [edit] your question to reflect those facts. Mind to include what is defined where and what should be used where. There are definitely ways to solve your issue like delegation of facts (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegating-facts) but that all depends what you really need.

Answer (score 0):

set the variable value to "!!null" (without double quotes) to undefine the variable :)